# How can I format each line while reading a file?

Tags: perl, insert, line

Input format:

```
2014-09-21 00:09:22,718 TRACE [user: admin12] common.Log (PerformanceExtractor.Python:9776) - ClientId:895,UserId:258,Ip:111.1.1.1,DurationMls:23,DurationString:0.023 seconds,Url:Calculate.LoanExmple
```

My output would be into variables; for example:

```
$date = 2014-09-21 00:09:22,718 $user = admin12 $ClientId= 895 $UserID=258 $ip = 111.1.1.1 $time=0.023 $url=Calculate.LoanExmple
```

In JAVA I would tackle this using a loop, a Stream Object, and a regular expression. I have no idea how to tackle this using Perl. I will also insert this variable as a column into a database and the line will be at least 3000 max 5000 each time i will launch the .pl.

my loop is

```
{
print $line;

--formatting here?

last if $. == 500;

}
```

This just prints out the line as above - I guess the best solution would be to format it and get the values into variables while reading each line, ready to INSERT into DB with DBI libraries.

any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to format the lines (i.e. print them out in some manner), or do you want to *parse* the lines--extract the data to variables and then save it?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
while (<$fh>) {
    my @fields = m{^
        (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:[\d,]+)
        \s TRACE \s
        \[user:\s(\w+)]
        \s common.Log \s \(PerformanceExtractor\.Python\:\d+\) \s - \s
        ClientId:(\d+),
        UserId:(\d+),
        Ip:([\d.]+),
        DurationMls:\d+,
        DurationString:([\d.]+) \s seconds,
        Url:(\S+)
    $}x
        or next;  # skip lines which don't match regexp

    printf('$date=%s; $user=%s; $client_id=%s; $user_id=%s; $ip=%s; $time=%s; $url=%s', @fields);
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: my $file = 'C:\Users\text.txt';
while(<$fh>)  {
 my @fields = m{^
        (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:[\d,]+)
        \s TRACE \s
        \[user:\s(\w+)]
        \s common.Log \s \(PerformanceExtractor\.Python\:\d+\) \s - \s
        ClientId:(\d+),
        UserId:(\d+),
        Ip:([\d.]+),
        DurationMls:\d+,
        DurationString:([\d.]+) \s seconds,
        Url:(\S+)
    $}x
        or next;  # skip lines which don't match regexp
    printf('$date=%s; $user=%s; $client_id=%s; $user_id=%s; $ip=%s; $time=%s; $url=%s', @fields);
}

tried but not working :(

Comment: You need to actually open the file. If `$file` is a filename and you want `$fh` to be a filehandle, then: `open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Could not open $file for input: $!";`

Comment: yep you were right - now i will play with it and i will need to understand how to treat lines which are in different format for example insteead TRACE i will have INFO - sometimes userid and clinet id do not get log and instead i have a text string referring to a SQL statements - but i think that this RegEx will open the path to glory - it is so powerful PERL :)

Comment: Hi toby i have been plaiyng around a lot with this and it's getting better PERL looks amazing - especially the DBI libraries are useful; I am having hard time with the REGEX but i think i have a solution - i mean logically if i have on the log line instead TRACE but INFO or ERROR can i put a OR condition in the regex so it can catch that too;example \s TRACE \s OR \s INFO\s OR\s DEBUG\s - is that possible ? or i better createa nother regex thathandles that?

Comment: `\s (TRACE|INFO|DEBUG) \s` - note that because the alternatives are in parentheses, this will be captured into the `@fields` array too. If you don't want this added to `@fields` then use `\s (?:TRACE|INFO|DEBUG) \s`

Comment: thanks Toby great progresses -  I cannot manage to take off the millisecond from the regular expression: at the moment we have (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:[\d,]+) that translate to 2014-09-21 00:09:22,718  ..... how can i just avoid to store ,718 and just get 2014-09-21 00:09:22? is there any way to do so?

Comment: Hi toby: perl is getting more and more interesting but i cannot figure out how to manage double spaces - in other word if between two varaibles I have not just one space but two spaces my regex does not perform at all : example:
  (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:[\d,]+)
    \s (ERROR|INFO|DEBUG|WARNING|TRACE) \s  # here my log file my have 2 spaces after the word TRACE or WARNING or.. i have tried /h/h no luck....
     \[SOAP\huser:\s(\w+)]   


how can i manage this?

Comment: example
2014-09-21 00:00:17,558 INFO  [user:..........   2 spaces between INFO and [  and will not get captured



2014-09-21 00:00:17,558 TRACE[user:..........   1 space between INFO and [ 

my regex just capture the string with one space....